# Difference between static const and const on a variable

Tags: objective-c, static, constants

There is  any difference between:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
const static NSString * name;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>


@end
```

and:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
const  NSString * name;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: I think is not a duplicate. I dont ask the general case. I ask specically for a question related to the specific case of global variables declared static.

Comment: The questions are exactly the same even in the title they are the same except that one has "What is the" at the beginning and yours has "on a variable" at the end. In what way aren't they the same question?

Comment: Yes you are right, can I delete the question?

Comment: There is no point you might as well allow it to be closed then the person who has answer still gets the rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` means that the scope of the variable is limited to this compilation unit. Without it, you wouldn't be able to have two variables called `NSString * name` in two different implementation files (duplicate symbols).

Comment: This answer is to the point of the question, it answers the question for the scope in the sample code: file scope.

Comment: I used kPrefFcmClientId in AppDelegate.m and ViewController.m without using static. I got following error.
duplicate symbol _kPrefFcmClientId.